# Lodash in Visual Studio HTML Typescript application

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, nuget, lodash

I'm trying to make a new HTML App with Typescript.
I installed the following plugin for Typescript : [Visual studio TypeScript](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fa041d2d-5d77-494b-b0ba-8b4550792b4d)

Now, using Nuget, i installed lodash, the packages config looks like:`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><packages><package id="lodash" version="4.13.1" targetFramework="net452" /></packages>`, so , it seems that the Lodash is installed.
A new folder is added in my solution : Scripts, with the following  `.js`-es :

```
lodash.core.js , lodash.core.min.js , lodash.js, lodash.min.js
```

In the `.ts` file i have an array :

```
var users = [
{ 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
{ 'user': 'fred', 'age': 40, 'active': false },
{ 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1, 'active': true }
];
```

I want to try this lodash function :`_.findKey(users, function(o) { return o.age < 40; });
// → 'barney' (iteration order is not guaranteed)`

The intellisense doesn't have any suggestion for `_.` typing.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install(via Nuget or manually) also the definition type for Lodash:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/lodash.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/

Quote from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html

> When using an external JavaScript library, or new host API, you’ll
>   need to use a declaration file (.d.ts) to describe the shape of that
>   library.

...then you have to declare a reference to the definition on top of your file:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/insertheredefinitionfilename.ts"/>
```

Quote from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html

> Triple-slash directives are single-line comments containing a single
>   XML tag. The contents of the comment are used as compiler directives.
>   The `/// <reference path="..." />` directive is the most common of this
>   group. It serves as a declaration of dependency between files.
>
> Triple-slash references instruct the compiler to include additional
>   files in the compilation process.